# Blazor get validation message for two properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a simple EditForm within a Blazor Server Side application. It has an bound property which changes another property which should also be validated by the form.

The form contains the following section

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputRechnungsnummer">Rechnungsnummer</label>
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="Input.Rechnungsnummer" id="inputRechnungsnummer" class="form-control" />
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.CustomerExists" />
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Rechnungsnummer" />
</div>
```

As you can see, I want to display two messages under this InputField.

The bond field calls a method to find customer details.

```
public int Rechnungsnummer 
{ 
    get => _rechnungsnummer; 
    set
    {
        _rechnungsnummer = value;
        SearchKunde();
    }
}
```

This method changed the value of my attribute

```
private void SearchKunde()
{

    /* LOGIC */
    
    if(name != null)
    {
        Kundenname = name;
        CustomerExists = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Kundenname = "";
        CustomerExists = false;
    }
}
```

The second attribute is defined as:

```
[Required]
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Rechnungsnummer ein")]
public bool CustomerExists { get; set; }
```

However the validation message for CustomerExists won't be displayed. It is only shown once I try to submit my form.

Does anybody know how I can achive to display the message after it's value has been changed?

Comment: Maybe you need to call `StateHasChanged()` after your call to `SearchKunde()`?

Comment: This question has more than enough detail. I was able to understand the problem and provide the solution. Please reopen it.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are a few problems here.

1: Blazor will not report an error for the property unless you either (A) Edit it in a Blazor input control (make the property "modified"), or (B) call `EditContext.Validate` which will validate all properties.

2: If your code runs asynchronously then you'd also need to call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` at the end.

Alternatively, if you bind your form to an `EditContext` instead of `Model` you could do something like this

```
<EditForm EditContext=@MyEditContext>
  ... your form stuff here...
</EditForm>

@code
{
  EditContext MyEditContext = new EditContext(new Person());

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    base.OnInitialized();
    MyEditContext.OnFieldChanged += FieldChanged;
  }

  private void FieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs args)
  {
    if (args.FieldIdentifier.FieldName == nameof(Person.FirstProperty))
    {
      FieldIdentifider fd = MyEditContext.Field(nameof(Person.OtherProperty));
      MyEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fd);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to get a property that isn't directly on the object your `EditForm` is bound to (e.g. `Model.Address.PostalCode`) you can do this

```
var fd = new FieldIdentifier(Model.Address, nameof(Address.PostalCode));
MyEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fd);
```

Comment: Regarding point 2 `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` do we have to do this in all the methods that are async?

Comment: Thanks Peter. This seems to be a pretty solution. I still have one question. How can I bind the attribute for the ValidationMessage now? Is there any way to do this by the context?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: @PeterMorris, in your code `args.FieldIdentifier.FieldName` might return 'FirstProperty' and `nameof(Person.FirstProperty)` would return 'FirstProperty which works. Say, for instance, you had `Person.Subclass.FirstProperty`. Is there a way in the `FieldChanged` method to differentiate between the `FirstProperty` that is on `Person.FirstProperty` versus `Person.Subclass.FirstProperty`?

Comment: @RyanBuening Updated

Comment: @PeterMorris what I was wondering was if it's possible to get the fully qualified property path of `args.FieldIdentifier.FieldName`. For example, say you had an EditContext that was bound to `Foo` and `Foo` contained `Foo.MailingAddress.City` and `Foo.LocationAddress.City`. `args.FieldIdentifier.FieldName` would return `City` for both `Foo.MailingAddress.City` and `Foo.LocationAddress.City`. Is there a way to determine which specific City field was changed? The MailingAddress City versus the LocationAddress City?

Comment: No there isn't. Blazor property ids are based on property name and immediate owning object. You'd have to use FluentValidation and manually execute validation on the root to get full paths. You can use FV in my Blazor-Validation library.